# why does postgres complain about "ca md too weak" when connecting with ssl

Tags: postgresql, openssl

I'm trying to setup a postgres server (version 10.4) with openssl access only. I created a self signed ca and the necessary private and public keys for the user and the server with easyrsa version 3 as described [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/v3.0.5/README.quickstart.md) and put it in the directories as stated [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ssl-tcp.html). Afterwards I added this line

```
hostssl  all  myname  192.168.0.0/16  cert
```

to the `pg_hba.conf` as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-CERT)
But when I try to connect to the database with

```
psql -h 192.168.0.222 "sslmode=verify-ca sslcert=myname.crt sslkey=myname.key"
```

this error message pops up

```
couldn't read certificate "myname.crt": ca md too weak
```

and in the server log

```
couldn't accept SSL-connection: success
```

(maybe the messages are not literally correct, I translated them from German)

That is funny, because when I look at my certificates with

```
easyrsa show-cert myname
```

I see the following lines (and more):

```
Certificate: 
   Data: 
   Version: 3 (0x2) 
   Serial Number: 
       don't show it here
   Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

and the same for my root certificate ca.crt and the certificate for the postgres server. So obviously the certificates are signed with sha256 method and not with md
What is even more funny, is that it worked in the beginning, and some days later, when I tried it again the above mentioned error message appeared and I'm quite sure that I didn't change any configuration meanwhile. Maybe some update of openssl or postgresql was in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `openssl*.cnf` file that you used with Easy-RSA. In the `[ CA_default ]` section there is an option `default_md` that should be set to `sha256`.

If you actually used the `easyrsa` script that comes with current 3.x versions of Easy-RSA then this is already set correctly in the `openssl*.cnf` file that ships with it. If you used a 2.x Easy-RSA version then you will need to edit this yourself.

Comment: In the openssl-easyrsa.cnf I found   

    `default_md      = $ENV::EASYRSA_DIGEST          # use public key default MD`

But I'm not quite sure what it means

Comment: That's the correct; the `easyrsa` script sets `EASYRSA_DIGEST` to `sha256`. So that should be right. Do you have more than one easyrsa installation perhaps?

Comment: I replaced the `default_md = $ENV::EASYRSA_DIGEST` with `default_md = sha256` and it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is a probably unholy mixture of the old easyrsa 2 and a new easyrsa 3 on my computer. The /etc/easy-rsa/openssl-easyrsa.cnf which is used by easyrsa version 3 belongs to the old easyrsa version 2. Maybe that caused the trouble

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the already generated keys, so that I can use them together with postgres? Otherwise I would have to build a hole new pki :-(

Comment: correction: for the new cert and key, I gave the full path, for the old ones just the name of the files in the $HOME/.postgresql/ directory. Just for fun I tried to give the full path also for the old files (cert and key) and it works!! So the error message `ca md too weak` is **very** misleading